# How to get SelectedValue from AJAX Cascading DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I managed to make AJAX Cascading DropDownLists through this guide:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-Cascading-DropDown-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx

But when I tried to add a simple submit button which call

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(ddlCountries.SelectedValue + "|" + ddlCities.SelectedValue + "|" + ddlStates.SelectedValue);
}
```

I got the error

> invalid postback or callback argument.

I tried to add `AutoPostBack = "false"` but it's not working
then I tried to add `EnableEventValidation="false"` and it works but I dont want to use that way
How can I get the SelectedValue of those Cascading DropDownList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have code in your Page_Load() event then might be solved this issue.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{ 
//your code here 
}
```